# Awk file shows an error

Tags: udp, gawk, ns2

i run a simulation with udp connection and cbr application in ns2.
I run an awk file to show some results. I have 10 nodes and 2 of them (n0 and n10) send packets to each other. My problem is that i run these 2 codes to get result for both nodes but only the first one runs smoothly (n0 => n10):

> 1)gawk -f stats.awk src=0 dst=10 flow=0 pkt=512 file.tr
>
> 2) gawk -f stats .awk src=10 dst=0 flow=0 pkt=512 file.tr

The second code gives "division by zero attempted" error"
I don't include the stats.awk file here because it works in the first example so i guess the problem is something else? eg the flow in the second line is 0? i tried other numbers too but nothing happened.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obviously, we cannot help you. Obviously, somewhere in your hidden code you do some division. Obviously, the denominator there is zero.

Comment: Please start with the "top 20 awk scripts". (See your previous thread.) The awk script must be a match for your trace file. If no luck, please check the other ~135 awk scripts.  There are multiple files by name `stats.awk`. Which one are you using ?

Comment: `gawk` is just an implementation of `awk`. If you tag your questions with `awk` in addition to `gawk` you'll get vastly more people reading them and get multiple answers almost immediately.